# Erro conexão com banco de dados

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Ao tentar fazer uma conexão com o banco de dodos estou com o seguinte erro:

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@delphix-db-1.homolog.infra:1521:BRMQA10
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>     at br.com.oiinternet.oitestautomation.sga.page.DataBase.main(DataBase.java:28)
> ```

Segue código que estou utilizando:

```
package br.com.oiinternet.oitestautomation.sga.page;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DataBase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sql;

        /*
         * O driver JDBC do Oracle está disponível no seguinte endereço:
         * http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html
         */

        // Configuração dos parâmetros de conexão
        String server = "delphix-db-1.homolog.infra";
        String port = "1521";// Porta TCP padrão do Oracle
        String database = "BRMQA10";

        // Configuração dos parâmetros de autenticação
        String user = "****";
        String passwd = "*****";

        try {
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + server + ":" + port + "/" + database;
            // String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@""delphix-db-1.homolog.infra:1521/BRMQA10";
            /// Abre-se a conexão com o Banco de Dados
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Dados do Banco:

nome host : delphix-db-1.homolog.infra
porta : 1521
Nome do serviço : BRMQA10

Como corrigir esse erro ?

Comment: Você adicionou o driver jdbc do Oracle no classpath?

Comment: Sim, eu baixei direto desse site :http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Fui em add external jars e add direto no eclipse

Comment: Está usando o maven?

Comment: Sim, estou usando.

Comment: O erro ocorre rodando por dentro do eclipse?

Comment: Sim, dentro do eclipse.